# nginx allow range by passes basic auth using ip address but not via domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

accessing 10.0.0.8/sonarr bypasses the basic auth yet accessing by mydomain.com/sonarr doesnt.

could someone please tell me what im doing wrong

my router is 10.0.0.1 with a sub net of 255.255.255.0

ive tried
10.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 even 10.0.0.0/24 which works for subs

this is the top snip it of my nginx i have more proxies

````
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;


    server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;


   }

  server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.com, 10.0.0.8;


satisfy any;
         allow 10.0.0.1;


         ssl_certificate mydomain.com-chain.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key mydomain.com-key.pem;

    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_dhparam dhparam.pem;

    location /{
            root   html;
            index  index.php


        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

        }

        location /nzbget {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.8:6789;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
satisfy any;
    allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }

      location /plexpy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/plexpy;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
satisfy any;
    allow 10.0.0.0/24;

        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }```
````

Comment: The `server_name` directive should not include a `,` separator. The names should be separated using whitespace only.

Comment: before I swapped over to my new router every worked fine even with the , separator